# Hello World in assembly on x86-64 Windows vs. Linux with int 0x80 system call

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

I'm just starting out in the world of Assembly and I made this little code in a Linux environment with the help of a book, but I'd like to compile and run the code in a Windows environment.

```
section .data
  var_msg db 0xA,'hello world', 0xA, ; Nessa sessão armazena-se variáveis
  var_len equ $ - var_msg                ; Variavel len que  recebe o tamanho da string


section .text
global _start

_start:
  mov eax, 4            ; Metodo de escrita (sys_write)
  mov ebx, 1            ; Metodo de saida (std_out)
  mov ecx, var_msg      ; Armazenar Mensagem
  mov edx, var_len      ; Armazenar Tamanho
  int 0x80              ; Chamando o Kernel

  mov eax, 1            ; Metodo de Saída
  int 0x80              ; Chamando o Kernel
```

I am compiling on Linux using:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o
ld -s -o hello hello.o
./hello
```

And Windows:

```
nasm -f win64 hello.asm -o hello.o
ld hello.o -o hello.exe
```

When I compile in Windows it doesn't give any errors, but running it doesn't show hello world on the screen the way it does on Linux.

Comment: Your problem is the `int 0x80`. That's a call to the OS, and it is ignored by the Windows OS. Hopefully someone else will give you a more complete answer.

Comment: For Linux, you should be building with `nasm -felf32` and `ld -m elf_i386`.  In this case the 32-bit `int 0x80` system-call interface works because your pointer is in the low 32 bits of address-space since its in static storage in a non-PIE executable, but it would break if you wanted to print a character from the stack.  And other examples from your book will do stuff like `push ebx` which won't assemble in 64-bit code.

Comment: Windows has a totally different system-call interface; see the linked duplicates (list at the top of this page)